# What does this package json command line do: sass .storybook/index.scss dist/index.css?

Tags: css, sass, package.json

The full command line is this:

```
sass --load-path=node_modules --style=compressed --no-source-map .storybook/index.scss dist/index.css
```

but I am mostly interested in the last part: `.storybook/index.scss dist/index.css`

I have been told this command line `listens to css changes and does hot code replacement` but I have little idea of what is that mean exactly. I know what it means to `listen to CSS changes`, but which css changes are being `listened` to? In the storybook folder, `index.scss` just imports bootstrap sass files, and the `dist/index.css` file just contains the compiled sass. So, is the `.storybook/index.scss` being listened to?

What is the purpose of having the second file `dist/index.css` written in the command if it's not `listened` to?

Also, what is meant by `'hot code replacement'` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.storybook/index.scss is being compiled to: dist/index.css

That's all it means. It is not listening to changes in the dist/index.css